# When a scala recover should be used:

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a simple flow of orders from an controller to services back to the controller, and im trying to make sure I use future recovers in the right place and in general to cover exceptions properly.

controller action:

```
def getSiblings(): Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[Person] match {
      case JsSuccess(person, _) =>
        peopleService.getSiblings(person).map(res => Ok(Json.toJson(res))) recover {
          case t: Throwable =>
            logger.error("error running getSiblings: ", t)
            InternalServerError
        }
      case JsError(errors) => Future(BadRequest(s"not a good person format ${errors.mkString}"))
    }
  }
```

peopleService:

```
class PeopleService @Inject() extends LazyLogging {

  def getSiblings(personToGetSiblings: Person): Future[List[SiblingResults]] = {
    // isSibling is a method of a person that returnes a future and can fail
    Future.sequence(listOfPeople.map(person => person.isSibling(personToGetSiblings))) recover {
      case e: Exception => {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail to get siblings with error: ", e)
      }
    }
  }

}

case class SiblingResults (person: Option[Person])
```

and a Person:

```
@Singleton
class PersonA @Inject() (configuration: Configuration, peopleApi: PeopleApi) extends Person {

   def isSibling(personToMatch: Person): Future[SiblingResults] = {
    val res = for {
        // areSiblings returnes a Future[Boolean]
        areThey <- peopleApi.areSiblings(personToMatch, personInstance) recover {
            case ex: Exception => throw new Exception("PeopleApi failed")
        }
    } yield areThey

    if (res) Some(personInstance) else None
  }

  val personInstance = this

 ...

}
```

what will be the right way to recover those futures?

Answer (score 0):

Use Play's Action composition to handle any failures. This your code would be clean handling only the business logic without the extra plumbing stuff like exception handling etc. You let the exceptions bubble up to the controller and exception is handled finally by the ActionBuilder.

**ActionBuilder**

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc.{ActionBuilder, Request, Result}
import play.api.mvc.Results.Status
import scala.concurrent.Future


/**
  * Created by chlr on 12/2/16.
  */
object ErrRecoveryAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: Request[A] => Future[Result]) = {
    block(request) recover errorHandler
  }

  def errorHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, Result] = {
    // you can apply a different statuscode other than 500 depending on the type of exception matched.
    case th: Throwable =>
      new Status(500).apply(Json.obj("error_message" -> th.getMessage, "error_class" -> th.getClass.getName))
  }

}
```

**Controller usage**:

Note how there is no exception handling in the controller and furthermore no exception handling is required in other service classes.

```
def getSiblings(): Action[JsValue] = ErrRecoveryAction.async(parse.json) { 
    request => 
         peopleService
           .getSiblings(request.body.as[Person])
           .map(res => Ok(Json.toJson(res))) 
}
```